# Nginx proxy_pass failover to an url instead of a server

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have an endpoint requesting my database through Symfony :
api.domain.com:80/item/123

When this endpoint is requested, Ngninx will proxy pass it to a nodejs server able to get the item from memcache :
127.0.0.1:8000/item/123

If the item is not found in memcache it get it from another PHP endpoint :
api.domain.com:80/item/db/123

It works well but I do not see how to manage a nodejs failure. If the nodejs does not respond anymore I would like to ignore the proxy_pass or use the second endpoind (/item/db/123).

My Nginx config is :

```
upstream itemFromNodeJs {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name api.domain.com 127.0.0.1;

    location ~*\/item\/([0-9]+)$ {
        proxy_pass http://itemFromNodeJs;
    }
```

I tried to add a backup server into the upstream :

```
upstream itemFromNodeJs {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000;
    server 127.0.0.1:80;
}
```

Of course, it cannot work : infinite loop when the nodejs is down.

The only solution I have in mind is to create a specific server for getting data from database :

```
upstream itemFromNodeJs {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000;
    server 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```

But I have to duplicate the whole server : it's far from elegant.

Any other idea ?

Comment: May be you need `error_page`?

Answer (score 1):

Good advice from Alexey !
Here is my new config:

```
upstream itemFromNodeJs {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name api.domain.com 127.0.0.1;

     location ~*\/item\/([0-9]+)$ {
        proxy_pass http://itemFromNodeJs;
        error_page 502 = /item/db/$1;
    }
    ...
}
```

So what happens now ?
If the nodejs server is alive, the proxy_pass works and we do not go further.
If the nodejs server is down, the error_page intercept the 502 error and goes to the fallback url, including the url parameter ($1). The = makes it change the status code from 502 to the one returned by the fallback URL.
That's exactly what I wanted.

One could say this is a "cheat and cheap way" to play with the semantic: an error page is an error page, and not a fallback. I agree, but this is also a respectable logic : my proxy server (nodejs) is down, thus giving an error...

If anyone has another solution, I am still interested !